# Introduction to D-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I would like to ask you, how to start learning the theory of D-modules from the point of view of algebraic topology. What are the pre-requisites for that ?, and more important: what is the logical order to study them?. I have a solid background in algebraic geometry and theory of sheaves.

Comment: What do you mean by "from the point of view of algebraic topology"? In any case there are some standard references, for example the book "Introduction to algebraic D-modules" by Borel. There are also nice notes by Bernstein that you can find online (just google it). A solid background in algebraic geometry should be enough for either of those.

Comment: To add to @Rieux's comment, Borel's book [is online](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~scautis/dmodules/boreletal.djvu) as are [Bernstein's notes](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Unpublished_texts/unpublished_texts/Bernstein82-dmod-from-chicago.pdf). For a more recent reference, there is a book by [Hotta, Takeuchi, and Tanisaki](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4523-6); the beginning follows Bernstein's presentation. A more beginner-friendly book is [Coutinho's](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511623653). But I, too, would like to know what "the point of view of algebraic topology" is.

Comment: I have read that the theory can be attacked from an analytic point of view or from a more algebraic perspective.